# Is 64 bits less efficient than 32 bit when 64 is not required?

Tags: 64-bit

I was wondering what "64 bit" actually means, and when I started looking into it, the more vague and unclear the entire topic seems to be. There are no hard and set rules here, everything is "may use" and "is capable of". Unless you need 64 bits for a specialist reason, is it true that using a 32 bit (if not lower) system or program would be far more efficient, because most of the bits in the 64 bits will be empty anyways?

Comment: The processor designers did not screw this up.  That would not be good for business.  It is about a wash.  Target 64-bit if you need the address space, target 32-bit if you need to support users that maintain old machines.

Comment: ............? But what if I don't need the extra space? Who would need 64 bits of extra space? I mean, the furthest we've gone from 4 GB was 16GB of RAM that's actually used. That's, what, just another 2 extra bits?

Comment: It is impossible to not discover this.  Just as you can't help discover that users that don't update their machines are a pita to have to support.  If you have no idea what to pick and your team or sales staff can't provide insight then flip a coin.

Comment: I am recommend for review: Why do 64-bit applications work faster than 32-bit ones? - https://www.viva64.com/en/k/0003/

Comment: Guys, it's like nobody here understands what 32 vs 64 bit actually means. 64 bits means that you can have up to 64 bits of binary for a single variable. Does anybody here know if this will mean that most of the 64 bits will go to waste, since I can't think of many applications where you will need anything even close to 64 bits? Meaning that most of the 64 will be empty 0s?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a video that might help slightly. Might be good to remember 64 bit is compatible with 32 bit and 32 bit is NOT compatible with 64bit. A bit has to do with binary (computer language) and it can have 2 values (0 or 1). The computer takes multiple bits and connects them into chunks called bytes and we use these bytes to talk to the computer using programming. bits are standard 1,2,4,8,16,32,64 values and all modern programming languages need to be translated into bits before actually being used by the computer to run the program.

more resources:
https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/b/bit.htm
[32bit vs 64bit](https://youtu.be/iH5D0e_L6a8)>